# Tensorflow indexing 2-D matrix update

Tags: python, indexing, machine-learning, tensorflow

I' m new in Machine Learning coding and totally new in coding with Tensorflow.

I' m facing problems using indexing in Tensorflow. In simple python with numpy it is pretty easy but in the Tensorflow library I cannot figure out how to make it.

I want to apply the softmax function not in every class of an example, but only in two random classes for every line and return those values in the big matrix (of zeros initially) of all the classes in specific indexes(of the random classes taken before). The algorithm in numpy is easier because simple indexing is available, but in tensorflow i think of it like that:

Given a matrix X:(NxD) and a matrix W:(KxD) and an array rem_cl of two random numbers between 0 and K-1

```
S is an empty matrix
for every line in X
   take Wsamp = W[rem_cl] 
   mult = X[line] * Wsamp.T
   apply softmax on mult
   put those numbers in an array "s" of zeros (1xK) in the indexes of rem_cl
   append s in S
```

The matrix S finally would have shape (NxK)

The tensorflow code that i've made untill now is:

```
Xnp = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1,2],[4,2,1,0,0],[3,0,1,1,2],[1,2,1,0,0]], np.float32)
K = 4
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((K,5)))
rand = tf.random_uniform((),0,K-1, tf.int32)
s = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((K)))
S = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((K)))
for line in range(4):
    rem_cl = tf.constant([sess.run(rand),sess.run(rand)])   
    Wsampled = (tf.gather(W,rem_cl))
    mult = (tf.matmul(Xnp[line:line+1],Wsampled,transpose_b=True))
    mult = (tf.nn.softmax(mult)) 
    rem_cl = tf.reshape(rem_cl,(2,1))
    rem_cl = tf.transpose(rem_cl)
    k = sess.run(tf.scatter_update(s,rem_cl,mult))
    sess.run(s.assign(tf.zeros(K)))
    S = tf.pack([S,k], axis=0)
```

The last line gives the following error

> Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
>       From merging shape 0 with other shapes.

My questions are:
1) First of all, is there a simpler way to update array-specified values of a matrix in Tensorflow?
2) if not, why that error is coming out, or better said, how can one append a new line to an existing matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Python loop, I would just use a Python list of Tensors. If you end up using a TensorFlow while_loop (helpful for keeping the graph small), I would look into using a TensorArray (or one of the higher-level looping constructs like scan() which use it implicitly).

As for the error just for completion's sake, I think you'd want [concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat), with an [expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#expand_dims) for the vector. Pack adds a dimension and requires its arguments to have the same shape.